# UIbutton should not scroll with view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button, uibutton

I am trying to make an app, which has a table view and a button. When you scroll down through the cells, the button should stay in the same position of the screen. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your button a subview inside your scrollview? If you place it outside if the scroll view, it won't scroll alongside it.

Comment: Use a UIViewController with a tableview and a button in it. Make sure the button is placed in the main view and not the table view. Make sure the button is layered above the table view. Boom... your done! Don't use a UITableViewController, because then your main view is a tableview and you can't do what your talking about... at least not in a good way.